# Heroku does not show up my images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, 12factor

I have a problem, my images does not show up on heroku .. 
There are no error messages in the push and I installed the  gem 'rails_12factor' in my gemfile ..

So I do not really know what to do

The adress is http://middiz.herokuapp.com/

Could you have a look guys and help me please ?

Thx so much

[image: image desc]

Comment: I can see images. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you the backgrounds ? it is weired only the incones show up ..

Comment: you have hardcoded the images by yourself or used image_tag? show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see some images, but for posterity & to give you an idea as to what the problem may be, I thought I'd better write this answer to help you run images on Heroku

---

**Dynamic CSS**

CSS-based images change when you pre-compile them & deploy to Heroku. Rails uses [asset fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) to link the dependent asset files to the asset itself. This means you have to ensure your css has dynamic image paths, rather than static ones, and the way to do this is to use [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/)

SCSS allows you to dynamically insert values into the asset pipeline, thus allowing you to serve images dynamically. Here's how it works:

```
#app/assets/application.css
background-image: url('background.png'); /* --> Renders static asset every time */

#app/assets/application.css.scss
background-image: image_path('background.png'); /* --> dynamically renders the fingerprinted path */
```

---

I appreciate it's not a direct fix for you, but I hope it shows a way to fix the problem

Comment: Hey, thx you so much for your answer it gave me a path to dig in ..     Actually I use the asset-url to get it to work ..            background-image: asset-url('bg.png'); That is it ! thx you so much

Comment: Can I ask you another question .. could you have a look at http://middiz.herokuapp.com/ when I reduce the size of my windows my divs get messy .. why ?

Comment: No problem! The DIVs look fine to me? Are you using Booststrap or something similar?

Comment: Yes I use bootstrap .. I uploaded you an image of how it render on my computer .. the icones and other get one over the other ..

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there any way you could show us the direct URL? My initial presumption is that your added DIVs will be interfering with Bootstrap somehow. Only way to test is to see the page!!

Comment: Thx you ! Cannot you see the page via heroku ? here is my github account where you ll be able to see the code ..  https://github.com/Ben2pop/MidiPiano

Comment: Hey sorry!! Is there any way you could let us know which view you're loading when you posted those problems? :)

Comment: Hi :-) it is the pages/home view. my problem occurs when I reduce my windows size ... It should be responsive so some div react properly other do not :-(